# jquery remove hidden form value after form submit

Tags: php, jquery, shopping-cart

I have a small form and I need `jquery` to clear the hidden form value after the form has been submitted.

Here is a snippet from my form

```
<select id='size'>
    <option value='4.99'>S</option>
    <option value='5.99'>M</option>
    <option value='6.99'>L</option>
    <option value='7.99'>XL</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" id="my-item-price" name="my-item-price" value="" />
```

and the `jquery` which changes the hidden field value

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#size').change(function() {

        var x= $(this).val();
        $('#my-item-price').val(x);
    });
}
```

the problem is once I have submitted the form, I want the value to be erased from the hidden input.  I expect that i have to set the value to `""` but how do I do it?

---

**EDIT -:**

Here is a [link](http://www.operationbraveheart.org.uk/jcart/) to a testing part of my site

What I want to do is once the button is clicked, it resets the hidden form value to nothing so when i make a new selection, it changes the value again

Here is the code for the `jquery`.

```
    function clearoption() {
            alert('it should work');
            $('#my-item-price').attr('value','');
        }

        $('#size').change(function() {

            var x= $(this).val();
            $('#my-item-price').val(x);
        }); 

      // Add an item to the cart
      $('.jcart').submit(function(e) {
         add($(this));
         clearoption();
         e.preventDefault();
      });
```

It's calling the function to clear the `#my-item-price` but for some reason it's not doing it.  If i make a different size selection it still adds the original price

Comment: Any way you can post a link to the site? You say that setting the hidden value field does not work. What code are you using to do this? It should work. Unless the code you used is incorrect or it is getting reset later on by something else. Hard to tell without a page to look at.

Comment: I've added a link to the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ajax to submit the form then in the success part, you can use following code

```
 $(' #myform input:hidden').attr('value','');
```

or

```
$('#my-item-price').attr('value','');
```

else if u r not using ajax for submitting form then clearing hidden fields wont make sense.

also, it would be a lot easier if u can post link to your page!

**EDIT:**
To trigger/update the change to the

tag where the price is displayed, you need to do following:

```
$(' #myform input:hidden').attr('value','').trigger('change');
```

I think this should work

Comment: Tarun has it I believe. I just checked out the page you posted and it seems to work as expected. Have you implemented his fix? For me, I switch size and my-item-price updates. I click Add to Cart and the value of my-item-price becomes nothing again.

Comment: I tried it but i couldn't get it to work.  What happens is i select a size and add to cart which gives the right price but when i select a different size, it doesn't change the price but keep the old one.  I don't really know where in the jcart.js i put that code. Have you any ideas?

Comment: Ahh, I see. I don't know who is responsible for updating the visible price - you or jcart. If it is you then you also need to update the visible price. Do you know who handles this?

Comment: @mrtsherman... I think you want to clear the value of the <p> tag instead. editing my original post